# What is the simplest way to share one of my libraries among my React Typescript projects?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, yarnpkg, npm-link

Suppose I want to share some common data object or utility classes among my React projects (locally only). For example, a utility class that performs complex string or data structures manipulation.

Which would be the best way of doing it? Should I create a separated NPM module for the library, and link it to each project?

I have seen some solutions that use `create-app-rewired`, but they require some custom `getBabelLoader` stuff and it seems too much for such a simple use case.

Comment: how about `yarn link`?

Answer (score 1):

You can setup Yarn workspaces & have scoped package names like `@project/libraryA` or `@project/libraryB`. You can then import using `import { someFunc } from '@project/libraryB'` in `@project/libraryA`

You'll want to export all the functions you want to share in your package.json `main` field, which usually points to index.js.

I would do more research on monorepos.

A great tool I found recently is https://nx.dev. It is a Monorepo build tool similar to the one found in Angular CLI, but this works for React as well.